# Calculating holidays: number of saturdays and sundays within the given date range query in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to calculate holidays: the number of Saturdays and Sundays within the given date range query in Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the **ROW GENERATOR** technique to first generate the dates for a given range, and then count only the **SATURDAYs and SUNDAYs**.

For example, this query will give me the total count of saturdays and sundays between 1st Jan 2014 and 31st Dec 2014 -

```
SQL> WITH DATA AS
  2    (SELECT to_date('01/01/2014', 'DD/MM/YYYY') date1,
  3      to_date('31/12/2014', 'DD/MM/YYYY') date2
  4    FROM dual
  5    )
  6  SELECT SUM(holiday) holiday_count
  7  FROM
  8    (SELECT
  9      CASE
 10        WHEN TO_CHAR(date1+LEVEL-1, 'DY','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=AMERICAN') IN ('SAT', 'SUN')
 11        THEN 1
 12        ELSE 0
 13      END holiday
 14    FROM data
 15      CONNECT BY LEVEL <= date2-date1+1
 16    )
 17  /

HOLIDAY_COUNT
-------------
          104

SQL>
```

Comment: You're welcome. Please mark it as answered if it has solved your issue.

Comment: @VishwanthGoud Please mark it as answered, would help others.