# sql oracle ignore holidays

Tags: sql, oracle, date, oracle-sqldeveloper, weekend

I am using this code to calculate the difference between two dates ignoring weekends:

```
SELECT To_date(SYSDATE) - 
      To_date('01.07.2014', 'DD.MM.YYYY') 
      - 2 * ( TRUNC(Next_day(To_date(SYSDATE) - 1, 'FRI')) 
      - TRUNC( Next_day(To_date('01.07.2014' , 'DD.MM.YYYY') 
      - 1, 'FRI')) ) / 7 AS DAYS_BETWEEN
FROM dual
```

I have another table called table1 in which the column "date" exists (its type is "DATE") in which all dates where a holiday is are written down.

Example table 1:

```
DATES

12.06.2011
19.06.2014
09.05.2013
...
```

I am trying to make my code check this table and that if one date is between the two dates above it makes -1 day in the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be easy if you divide it into following tasks:

- Generate all the dates between the two given dates using **Row Generator** method as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28405901/3989608).
- Ignore the dates which are weekend, i.e. **Saturdays and Sundays**
- Check whether the dates in the range are having any match in the **holiday table**.

The following **row generator query** will give you the **total count of weekdays**, i.e. **not** including **Saturdays and Sundays**:

```
SQL> WITH dates AS
  2    (SELECT to_date('01/01/2014', 'DD/MM/YYYY') date1,
  3      to_date('31/12/2014', 'DD/MM/YYYY') date2
  4    FROM dual
  5    )
  6  SELECT SUM(weekday) weekday_count
  7  FROM
  8    (SELECT
  9      CASE
 10        WHEN TO_CHAR(date1+LEVEL-1, 'DY','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=AMERICAN')
 11             NOT IN ('SAT', 'SUN')
 12        THEN 1
 13        ELSE 0
 14      END weekday
 15    FROM dates
 16      CONNECT BY LEVEL <= date2-date1+1
 17    )
 18  /

WEEKDAY_COUNT
-------------
          261

SQL>
```

Now, based on above row generator query, let's see a test case.

The following query will calculate the count of working days between **1st Jan 2014** and **31st Dec 2014** excluding the holidays as mentioned in the table.

The **WITH** clause is only to use it as tables, in your case you can simply use your **holiday table**.

```
SQL> WITH dates
  2       AS (SELECT To_date('01/01/2014', 'DD/MM/YYYY') date1,
  3                  To_date('31/12/2014', 'DD/MM/YYYY') date2
  4           FROM   dual),
  5       holidays
  6       AS (SELECT To_date('12.06.2011', 'DD.MM.YYYY') holiday FROM   dual UNION ALL
  7           SELECT To_date('19.06.2014', 'DD.MM.YYYY') holiday FROM   dual UNION ALL
  8           SELECT To_date('09.05.2013', 'DD.MM.YYYY') holiday FROM   dual),
  9       count_of_weekdays
 10       AS (SELECT SUM(weekday) weekday_count
 11           FROM   (SELECT CASE
 12                            WHEN To_char(date1 + LEVEL - 1, 'DY',
 13                                 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=AMERICAN')
 14                                 NOT IN (
 15                                 'SAT',
 16                                 'SUN' ) THEN 1
 17                            ELSE 0
 18                          END weekday
 19                   FROM   dates
 20                   CONNECT BY LEVEL <= date2 - date1 + 1)),
 21       count_of_holidays
 22       AS (SELECT Count(*) holiday_count
 23           FROM   holidays
 24           WHERE  holiday NOT BETWEEN To_date('01/01/2015', 'DD/MM/YYYY') AND
 25                                      To_date('31/03/2015', 'DD/MM/YYYY'))
 26  SELECT weekday_count - holiday_count as working_day_count
 27  FROM   count_of_weekdays,
 28         count_of_holidays
 29  /

WORKING_DAY_COUNT
-----------------
              258

SQL>
```

There were total **261 weekdays**, out of which there were **3 holidays** in **holiday table**. So, total count of working days in the output is `261 - 3 = 258`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT To_date(sysdate)- To_date('01.07.2014','DD.MM.YYYY')
- (2 * (to_char(To_date(sysdate), 'WW') - to_char(To_date('01.07.2014','DD.MM.YYYY'), 'WW'))) AS DAYS_BETWEEN 
FROM dual
```

Comment: Hello Matt - isnt this the same like mine above?

Comment: Well I need to change my words: my code gives me 207 and yours 309 - does it exclude weekends?

Comment: @piguy try now, changed some brackets

Comment: still 309 here as output

Comment: I am using Toad for oracle